# Are static and mobile mounts of Gods called by different names?

Tags: name, terminology, vahana

Vishnu lies on Adisesha but uses Garuda to move around.  Garuda is called "vahana" I believe, but how about Sesha? What is Sesha considered?

Comment: He is called Bhagwan Vishnu’s shayanam. Hence he gets the name Anantashayanam or Sheshashayi